# MyModule-Swift.h not found

Tags: xcode, swift

Создал Framework:

```
framework module MyModule {
  umbrella header "MyModule.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}

module MyModule.Swift {
    header "MyModule-Swift.h"
}
```

Но при компиляции выдает ошибку:

> Header "MyModule-Swift.h" not found.

Что я сделал не так?

Swift2, XCode7.2, Defines Module YES. Приватность стоит `Public`. 
Такое ощущение, что не создается файл MyModule-Swift.h.